# conditional expectation of disjoint events

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, conditional-convergence

Let $B_{1},B_{2},\dots,B_{n} \in \mathcal{F}$
partition of $\Omega$

and $\mathcal{P}=\sigma(B_{1},B_{2},\dots,B_{n})$

If $P(B_j)>0 , j = 1,\dots,n$.

Then show that :

$$\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{P}] = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[X| B_{j}]\mathbf{1}_{B_{j}}$$
where :

$$\mathbb{E}[X|{B_i}] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[ X \mathbf{1}_{B_{j}}]}{P(B_{j})}$$

Hint : (all the non empty events of $\mathcal{P}$ have the form of $B_{j1} \bigsqcup B_{j2} \bigsqcup,\dots \bigsqcup B_{jk}$ )

With $\bigsqcup$ we denote the union of disjoint events.

My effort is :

\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}\left[X | B_{1} \bigsqcup B_{2} \bigsqcup,\dots \bigsqcup B_{j}\right] &= \frac{1}{P(B_{1} \bigsqcup B_{2} \bigsqcup \dots \bigsqcup B_{j})} \mathbb{E} \left[X \cdot \mathbf{1}_{B_{1} \bigsqcup B_{2} \bigsqcup,\dots \bigsqcup B_{j}} \right] \\
&=\frac{1}{   P\left( \bigsqcup_{j=1}^{n} B_{j} \right)  }\mathbb{E}\left[ X \left[ \mathbf{1}_{B_{1}} + \mathbf{1}_{B_{2}} + \dots + \mathbf{1}_{B_{j}} \right] \right] \\
&=\frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} P(B_{j})} \mathbb{E}(X\cdot \mathbf{1}_{B_{1}}) + \mathbb{E}(X \cdot \mathbf{1}_{B_{2}}) + \dots +\mathbb{E}(X \cdot \mathbf{1}_{B_{j}}) \\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[X| B_{j}]\mathbf{1}_{B_{j}}
\end{align*}

But why it says $B_{j1},B_{j2},\dots,B_{jk}$

**Proposal** :

\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}\left[X | B_{j1} \bigsqcup B_{j2} \bigsqcup,\dots \bigsqcup B_{jk}\right] &= \frac{1}{P(B_{j1} \bigsqcup B_{j2} \bigsqcup \dots \bigsqcup B_{jk})} \mathbb{E} \left[X \cdot \mathbf{1}_{B_{j1} \bigsqcup B_{j2} \bigsqcup,\dots \bigsqcup B_{jk}} \right] & \text{by definition}\\
&=\frac{1}{   P\left( \bigsqcup_{j=1}^{n} B_{j} \right)  }\mathbb{E}\left[ X \left[ \mathbf{1}_{B_{j1}} + \mathbf{1}_{B_{j2}} + \dots + \mathbf{1}_{B_{jk}} \right] \right]& \text{by mutual exclusivity} \\
&=\frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} P(B_{j})} \mathbb{E}(X\cdot \mathbf{1}_{B_{j1}}) + \mathbb{E}(X \cdot \mathbf{1}_{B_{j2}}) + \dots +\mathbb{E}(X \cdot \mathbf{1}_{B_{jk}})&\text{by linearity of expectation} \\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[X| B_{j}]\mathbf{1}_{B_{j}}
\end{align*}

[image]

Comment: any suggestion that might help me please ?

Comment: @Surb How is the proof correct? The right-hand side oscillates between being a scalar and a random variable. There are expressions of the form $\sum_{j=1}^n B_j$, which have no meaning. Even granting that this was meant to be $P(B_j)$, this is simply  $\sum_{j=1}^n P(B_j) = 1.$

Comment: @snar I edited you are right.I am using  $$P(\bigsqcup_{j=1}^{n}B_{j}) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} P(B_{j}) =1$$

Comment: Right. So how come
$$\frac{\sum_{j=1}^n E(X1_{B_j})}{\sum_{j=1}^n P(B_j)} = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{E[X 1_{B_j}]}{P(B_j)}1_{B_j} ?$$
Do you agree that the left-hand side is a number, while the right-hand side is a linear combination of indicator *functions* $1_{B_j}$, each of which are *functions* ?

Comment: @Snar : indeed, thanks for pointing out that. I thought that $\mathcal P$ was a set on the form $B_{i_1}\sqcup ...\sqcup B_{i_k}$ but in fact is a $\sigma -$algebra, so the proof is indeed wrong. I put an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

What has to be proved it's that for all $F\in \mathcal P$ (i.e. for $F$ of the form $B_{i_1}\sqcup\cdots \sqcup B_{i_k}$), $$\mathbb E[X\boldsymbol 1_F]=\mathbb E\left[\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb E[X|B_j]\boldsymbol 1_{B_j}\boldsymbol 1_F\right].$$

Try to adapt what you did in your original post to $\mathbb E[X\boldsymbol 1_F]$ and conclude.

---

**Edit**

We can suppose WLOG that $F=B_1\sqcup\cdots B_k$ (where $k\leq n$).

Then

\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[X\boldsymbol 1_F]&=\sum_{i=1}^k\mathbb E[X_i\boldsymbol 1_{B_i}]\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k\mathbb P(B_i)\mathbb E[X_i\mid B_i]\\
&=\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^k\mathbb E[X\mid B_i]\boldsymbol 1_{B_i}\right]\\
&=\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb E[X\mid B_i]\boldsymbol 1_{B_i}\boldsymbol 1_F\right],
\end{align*}
as wished.

Comment: as I have edited my question in the proposal you mean ?

Comment: @Mr.Podilatis: What you wrote in your proposal (especially the first equality) is wrong.

Comment: don't know how to do it @Surb

Comment: @Mr.Podilatis: I edited my answer.

Comment: What do you mean by wlog? Without loss of generality?

Comment: @Mr.Podilatis: Yes exactly.

Comment: the subscript is wrong I think.is $j$ not $i$ in the last equality

Comment: @Mr.Podilatis: There is no $j$... what I wrote is correct.

Comment: Can you explain?You are summing from $i$ to $k$ in $B$ ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I'm summing from $1$ to $k$... Notice that $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=\sum_{j=1}^n x_j=\sum_{p=1}^nx_p=\sum_{\Box=1}^nx_\Box...$$

Comment: You have substitute j with i

Comment: @Mr.Podilatis: Replace $i$ by $j$ if it's more clear for you... but as I wrote in my previous comment, both are correct...

Comment: But I have **3 questions**:


**1)** Why it has to be proved that : 

$$\mathbb E[X\boldsymbol 1_F]=\mathbb E\left[\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb E[X|B_j]\boldsymbol 1_{B_j}\boldsymbol 1_F\right].$$ 


**2)** 
What properties have been used in the proof in each equality (row)? 

**3)** Why $k \leq n $ ,and how interchange in the last equality ?

Comment: **1)** By definition of the conditional expectation. **2)** 
Please, check your self basic properties of conditional expectation **3)** By definition of $F$.

Comment: Briefly for **2)**, equality 2 : by definition , equality 3 : expection is $\mathbb R-$linear, and equality 3 : definition of $F$.

Comment: about **1)** you used : $$\mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr{P}(\omega) ]=\mathbb{E}[X|B_{j}]=\frac{1}{P(j)}\sum X(\omega)P(\omega)$$

\begin{align*}
    \sum_{\omega \in B_{j}}\mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr{P}(\omega)](\omega)P(\omega) &= \left( \frac{1}{P(B_{j})} \sum_{\omega \in B_{j}}X(\omega)P(\omega)  \right)  \sum_{\omega \in B_{j}}P(\omega)\\
    &=  \left(\frac{1}{P(B_{j})} \sum_{\omega \in B_{j}}X(\omega)P(\omega) \right)P(B_{j})\\ 
    &= \sum_{\omega \in B_{j}}X(\omega)P(\omega)
\end{align*}
?

Comment: I added a drawing if it correct.

Comment: @Mr.Podilatis: not at all. I even don't understand your first and second equality. As I said in my previous post, I highly recommend you to check basic properties of the conditional expectation.